# Self-signed certificate for own client

Tags: sockets, tcp, tls1.2

I am developing an app with a server part programmed in Go and a client programmed in C#, the connection between the two is made using TCP socket communication, and to ensure the connection I am using TLS.

My question is whether there would be any security problem in my case when using self-signed certificates for TLS communication.

I understand that for a web server that uses https it is necessary to use certificates signed by a certificate authority (CA) but in my case, when connecting my own client application I don't see why I should use one of these.

If anyone knows anything about it, it would be a great help.

Comment: Do the server and client each make sure the other one's certificate is the correct one?

Comment: The client does it, I use C# SslStrema to establish the communication and this requires a certificate validation method, however since it is a self-signed one, it will never be validated

Comment: Then you are supposed to insert your own certificate validation method. The other end sends a certificate and how do you know it's the right one? On the web you check if it's signed by a CA. In an app... you can just know what the right one is.

Comment: I understand but if my application only connects to my own server why should I validate it? What's wrong with trusting him without validating? My only intention using tls is to encrypt the communication...
Thanks

Comment: well how does it know it's actually connecting to your own server? because of the IP address? If your user's phone is connected to an evil person's wi-fi network, the evil person can easily redirect IP addresses

Comment: Yes, I understand, thank you very much for the help! Many doubts that were in my head were resolved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificates are used for authenticating the end points, and usually the cert is signed by a certificate authority which your client (such as a web browser) already [trusts](https://www.keyfactor.com/blog/certificate-chain-of-trust/). Using a self-signed cert in that scenario can lead to problems, as the browser won't trust it, and so will pop a warning box. However, the real issue is that for the typical user, a warning from your server is as good as indistinguishable from an attacker using another self-signed certificate. They'll click-away and *KABOOM*!

If this is a closed environment, and you control both the server and client, then the self-signed certificate is irrelevant. In fact, you don't even need one at all, and may be better off with one of the alternatives, like [TLS-PSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-PSK), or [TLS-SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-SRP).

Comment: The clients of my server will never be browsers, the consumer clients of my server will be through my own app developed in C#.

I have seen TLS-PSK or TLS-SRP but these solutions can not be a problem? any user can find out what is the symmetrical transmission key...

Comment: This is equally true for all forms of TLS: it protects against eavesdropping on the network, but it doesn't protect against an attacker already on an endpoint. If you want to stick with the self-signed cert approach, make sure to validate it in the client, and try to avoid disabling validation (as it will make the TLS easily circumventable).

Comment: Ah I understand! In that case, how could I validate the certificate? what's more... why would I need to validate it? My client application is only going to connect to my own server address... Is there any reason why I shouldn't trust it directly?

Comment: It all comes down to your threat model really. If you don’t validate the certificate in the client, and an attacker can gain access to the network anywhere between the client and server, then they can simply use another certificate and MITM the connection (which will work as there is no certificate validation). Certificate validation doesn’t have to be complicated though, it is enough to take a hash of the certificate and then compare it on the client at connection time (this is effectively cert pinning).

Comment: Great! Now I understand everything, verifying the certificate would allow me to prevent an attacker from impersonating the server without the client noticing! It is not like this?

I will use verification by hash, it seems a safe and easy option to implement

Comment: When using a certificate that is purchased from a CA, the client will check that the FQDN matches, and that the cert is signed by a CA that it trusts. For self-signed certs, you just need to confirm that it is the one you are expecting, and comparing the hashes is more than enough for this.